# how to get the multiple csv files on to the graph using Plotly library in python or any module that can get the results on browser?

Tags: python, csv, graph, plotly, data-visualization

Lets say I have multiple csv files for test_suites `UPT_Synergy_graph22.csv`, `UPT_C7000_graph22.csv`, `SAT-Synergy-gen2_graph22.csv`, **like this i have 10 more csv files, which are having the same columns in all the files build_id and pass percent**. I need to plot the line graph for all those files. where build id is x-axis and pass-percent is y-axis. I need to get line graph for each csv file (mean for each test suite). each csv file corresponds to one test_suite.

I was able to get the graph for only one csv file. I am able to get graph using matplotlib, but i want the graph on web page/browser, I got to know that we can use Plotly module/bookeh or any module that is able to get the same graph results on web would be helpful.

please help me to resolve this. below is the code i have used.  help me to convert the code using Plotly module to get the line graph for the csv files which mentioned above.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path
%matplotlib inline  

# graphing parameters
plt.style.use('seaborn')
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16.0, 10.0)

p = Path(r'c:\Users\shivarad\Documents')  # path to files
files = list(p.rglob('*graph22.csv'))  # get files

# everything for here down, belongs in one Jupyter cell
plt.figure()
for f in files:  # iterate through files
   file_name = f.stem  # get filename
   df = pd.read_csv(f, dtype={'Pass Percentage': int, 'original_pass_percent': int})  # create 
   dataframe

   print(df.head())  # this is here to verify df has data; it can be commented out or removed

   plt.plot('build ID', 'Pass Percentage', data=df, label=file_name)  # plot the data from each file

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 0.5), loc='center left')
plt.savefig('test.jpg')  # verify there's plot in the file
plt.show()  # outside the loop
```

Comment: @Andrea Blengino , Can you please help me to fetch the line graph using Plotly python library

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to concatenate or merge the files before. As you have your file list in the `files` variable and the columns are all the same, probably

```
dt = {'Pass Percentage': int, 'original_pass_percent': int}
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f).assign(filename=f, dtype=dt) for f in files])
```

then you can use plotly:

```
import plotly.express as px
px.line(df, x='build ID', y='Pass Percentage', color='filename')
```

assuming 'build ID' and 'Pass Percentage' are column names.